# How to capture the return value of timeout in linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell, c++11

Could any one please tell me how to capture the output of `timeout` utility.
As I have captured like below, but it is not getting as expected.

```
std::string syscommand = "timeout -s KILL 1s command";
int res = system(syscommand.c_str());
std::cout << res;
```

As I have gone through some post and I found output should be like below.

```
    124 if command times out
    125 if timeout itself fails
    126 if command is found but cannot be invoked
    127 if command cannot be found
    137 if command is sent the KILL(9) signal (128+9)
    the exit status of command otherwise
```

and how to print the error no too.

Comment: Why `std::string` (a C++ thing) in a question without any C++ tag? Maybe you want [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html). Your question is unclear. Read [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) and consider using directly system calls like `pipe`, `fork`, `execve`, `poll`, `waitpid`. See [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: Pleae read this.   http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html. Dont give -1 if you are not clear....

Comment: If you'd read the manpage you referenced, you'd see that you need to use the `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` macros to obtain the exit code. Also, your question needs an explanation of *what* doesn't work. What were you expecting and what did you get?